# Running Jest tests in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

Basically, the component isn't getting compiled, so I get an `Unexpected token <` error when it runs into `<template>`

I've run the following commands:

```
$ npm install --save-dev jest
$ npm install --save-dev vue-jest
$ npm install --save-dev vue-test-utils
```

and I've out the following in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },

...

"jest": {
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
        "<rootDir>/node_modules/vue"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "js",
        "vue"
    ],
    "scriptPreprocessor": "index.js"
}
```

I created a `__test__` folder in the root directory with a simple test:

```
const Vue = require("vue");
const VueTestUtils = require("vue-test-utils");

Vue.config.debug = true;
Vue.config.async = false;

Vue.use(VueTestUtils.install);

import Hello from '../src/components/Hello.vue'

const Constructor = Vue.extend(Hello)
const vm = new Constructor().$mount()

describe('initial test', () => {
  it('should be 1', () => {
    expect(1).toBe(1)
  })
})
```

I recently got this error as well, and not quite sure how to configure Vue.js so it will run using the compiler-included build:

```
[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.
```

Been looking around for a while, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: You should check this page, it explains the differences and how to setup runtime and full versions
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html

Comment: Thanks, I read a bunch of the guide but completely skipped this after installing by npm install vue vue-cli

Comment: Still no luck though after configuring the webpack build files, i'll update if I make progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [Jest transform](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#transform-object-string-string) to transform Jest Vue files. A Jest transformer is a synchronous function, that takes the file and path as input and outputs transpiled code.

I maintain a npm package that does it for you - [vue-jest](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest).

`npm install --save-dev vue-jest`

You need to add a `jest` section to your `package.json` (or in a seperate file with --config). Your config should look something like this:

```
  "jest": {
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "json",
    "vue"
  ],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
    ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest"
  }
}
```

This tells jest to use jest-vue as a transform for files with a .vue extension.

You can see a working repo using Vue Test Utils here - https://github.com/eddyerburgh/vue-test-utils-jest-example